# How do I install Urduhack in python 3.7?

Tags: python

Hi I would like to install `Urduhack` in my python3.7 So I tried

```
pip install Urduhack
```

and got the error message

```
tensorboard 2.1.1 has requirement grpcio>=1.24.3, but you'll have grpcio 1.14.1 which is incompatible.
tensorboard 2.1.1 has requirement setuptools>=41.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 39.1.0 which is incompatible.
mystic 0.3.3 has requirement numpy<1.16.0,>=1.0, but you'll have numpy 1.18.1 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: google-pasta, wrapt, keras-applications, gast, scipy, tensorflow, Urduhack
Found existing installation: wrapt 1.10.11
Cannot uninstall 'wrapt'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.
```

Can you help me to install the package?

Comment: It looks like you are having some environment issues.  Are you using a virtual environment?  I would suggest creating a new virtual environment and then try to install urduhack as the first install.

Comment: I'm not using virtual environment.My system's setting doesn't permit me to create virtual environment

Comment: Are you sure?  Try `$ python3 -m venv venv` on the command line and see if that does anything.  If using conda then try `$ conda create -- prefix ./venv python=3.7`

Comment: It looks like there are conflicting package versions, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try Install using this command.

```
pip install urduhack[tf]
```